# Use PHP variable at different moments in code

Tags: php

Is it possible to have use a php variable in multiple positions in the code? For example

```
<?php
some code here with a certain variable called var
?>

some html code
<h3> <?php $echo $var ?> <h3>
```

Comment: yes, then again no, depending the question; which as it stands unclear

Comment: The best way to tell is to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! PHP is wonderful that way. I like to think of it as an overlay on top of my HTML code that simply acts when I tell it to. You can test it for yourself and see - that's the best way to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
<?php
  $a = "hello world!";
?>

<h3> <?php echo $a ?> <h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a file is being interpreted as a PHP script you may think of it as a entire piece of code, the HTML code between  scripts works like a echo. So, if you declare a variable in any part of the script, if it is on the global scope, it is available for each of the  scripts declared. Just be careful with the scopes where you declare de variables. If you declare a variable inside a function, it will be available inside the function.